# Split string around colon

Tags: c#, .net-core

could you help splitting a string into key value pairs around the colon delimiter. I am having trouble with this.

eg.

```
"somekey:value1 value2 another:<value3 one_more:value4..value5"
```

output

```
<"somekey", "value1 value2">
<"another", "<value3">
<"one_more", "value4..value5">
```

Comment: Is the `<` in `key2:<value3` intentional?

Comment: yes. Its thats right. Updated the example

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: start by splitting on spaces, then on colons

Comment: your best option is RegEx, but you have to try and build something first, then ask questions.

Comment: Using `string.Split` will work just fine for this

Comment: i'm hoping the keys cannot contain spaces

Comment: @canton7. Ok I think I can first split on spaces. Then loop through, work out if the next has a key by whether it contains a colon. If it does push current to dictionary, if not append next to current value.

Comment: @TimRutter no spaces on keys

Comment: Post your code, then we can spot the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This if you just want a simple conversion. you can also use regex.

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary(string str)
        {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            var splitOnSpace = str.Split(" ");
            var value = string.Empty;
            var key = "";
            var i = 0;
            while (i < splitOnSpace.Length)
            {
                var item = splitOnSpace[i];
                if (item.Contains(":"))
                {
                    var split = item.Split(':');
                    key = split[0];
                    value = split[1];
                    dictionary.Add(key, value);
                }
                else
                {
                    value += " " + item;
                    dictionary[key] = value;
                }
                i++;
            }
            return dictionary;
        }
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking could be a solution after initial comments, plus avoids regex

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex.

```
string givenString =
@"key1:value1 value2 key2:<value3 key3:value4..value5";

Dictionary<string, string> result1 = Regex
          .Split(givenString, "([a-z0-9]+:)")
          .Skip(1)    // will skip the first empty                         
          .Select((item, index) => new {      
              value = item.Trim(),
              index = index / 2
          })
          .GroupBy(item => item.index)
          .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.First().value.TrimEnd(':'),
                        chunk => chunk.Last().value);
```

Comment: I have updated the question as there is no convention on the key. Could be anything

Answer (score 1):

The regex extracting such key-value pairs is

```
([^\s:]+):(.*?)(?=\s+[^\s:]+:|$)
```

([Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5b%5e%5cs%3a%5d%2b%29%3a%28.*%3f%29%28%3f%3d%5cs%2b%5b%5e%5cs%3a%5d%2b%3a%7c%24%29&i=key1%3avalue1+value2+key2%3a%3cvalue3+key3%3avalue4..value5))

The tricky part here is `(?=\s+[^\s:]+:|$)` lookahead, which tells the "match anything for value" regex (`(.*?)`) stop as soon as it encounters the next key preceded by some spaces (`\s+[^\s:]+:`) or simply end of string (`$`).

Then the match groups can be extracted as follows:

```
var input = "somekey:value1 value2 another:<value3 one_more:value4..value5";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"([^\s:]+):(.*?)(?=\s+[^\s:]+:|$)");

var pairs = matches.Select(m => (m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value));
foreach (var (key, value) in pairs)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"<\"{key}\": \"{value}\">");
}
```

[Full demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/shrnXL)

Comment: That looks very concise! Need to up my Regex skills! Looks good

Comment: Can we use, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @MaheshB. Using dotnet core 3. So yes

Comment: @MaheshB, yes, this is an option and @zetawars' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59664011/4295017) shows an example of going this way. (Well it actually employs `string.Split()` instead of `Regex.Split()` but basically the idea is the same.) However if consecutive spaces in the value should be preserved (i.e. `"somekey:value1_____value2"` should result into `<"somekey": "value1_____value2">` [replace underscores by spaces]), reconstructing the value after split by spaces could be painful. For this reason I find the Regex based solution easier in this particular case.